# How to convert a oauth2 token to a ACSID cookie?

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I made a appengine api that requires authentication. If I access it via web, I'm redirected to a google sigin process and then every request sends a ACSID cookie. Works flawlessly.

Now I want to use the api elsewhere. I already have a oauth2 token i got from logging in. From what I understood I should call `<myapp>.appspot.com/_ah/login?auth=<oauth2token>` and the request would return the cookie to pass to the future calls.

But it's returning status code 500, no matter the token I pass, and I'm reading about and starting to believe it's been deprecated. What's the proper way to do it now?

Comment: I have a similar question - I've got an appengine app that works flawlessly from the browser. I recently decided to create an API for that to integrate with voce assistants, which require the app to support oauth2. I think it's a similar problem as yours - how did you end up resolving it?

Comment: I ended up migrating my server to use firebase; it's really easy. The client uses a plethora of firebase clients for various platforms to obtain a key. Then I send it in the Authorization header and in the server every request I validate the key against firebase (using java's lib too). I believe the old login built into GAE is slowly dying, and the migration was easier than I thought.